# How to enable _metadata when writing a parquet dataset from Spark 3.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, pyarrow

I want to export a partitioned parquet dataset from pyspark, and later access the dataset using pyarrow.

I would like to import the dataset using the approach from the pyarrow docs, https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#working-with-parquet-datasets

```
dataset = ds.parquet_dataset("/path/to/dir/_metadata")
```

When using pyspark (Spark 3.3.0), the export of the _metadata file appears to be disabled by default.

```
df.write.partitionBy(['x']).parquet('path')
```

Is there any way to enable this file, or generate it?